# Time jump in Dimple Line Graphic

Tags: json, d3.js

I have a very basic time series data set of SOI values at monthly intervals from 1950 to 1995.
date    soi

```
1-Dec-94    2.993
1-Nov-94    1.293
1-Oct-94    -1.006
1-Sep-94    -0.80696
1-Aug-94    -1.406
1-Jul-94    -0.20696
1-Jun-94    -2.006
1-May-94    -0.90696
1-Apr-94    -1.806
1-Mar-94    -2.006
1-Feb-94    -1.306
1-Jan-94    -1.306
1-Dec-93    -1.706
1-Nov-93    -1.506
1-Oct-93    0.29374
1-Sep-93    -0.60696
1-Aug-93    1.2937
```

That is what it looks like.

I want to create a simple Dimple based line graphic. Here is my code:

```
<div id="chartContainer">  
  <script type="text/javascript" src="d3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://dimplejs.org/dist/dimple.v2.1.2.min.js"></script>
// This loads in dimple and d3 libraries
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var svg = dimple.newSvg("#chartContainer", 1000, 600);
    d3.csv("SOI_data.csv", function (data) {
      var myChart = new dimple.chart(svg, data);
      myChart.setBounds(60, 30, 800, 550);
      var x = myChart.addTimeAxis("x", "date", "%d-%b-%y", "%b-%y");
      x.addOrderRule("date");
      x.timeInterval = 4;
      myChart.addMeasureAxis("y", "soi");
      var s = myChart.addSeries(null, dimple.plot.line);
      myChart.draw();

    });
  </script>
</div>
```

And it executes but with a very odd output. It displays the data from Jan-69 to Dec-94 then has a large gap (with a connecting line between) to Jan-50 and then continues on correctly until Dec-68. All the day is displayed it is just displayed in two halves (with a connecting line). I don't know how to display an image or I would but simply put: The data is being graphed in two chunks out of order for no particular reason. I will include any other information if need be, this is my first stackover flow post, so thanks for any help!

Comment: make a fiddle, then we could help you....

Answer (score 0):

Under the hood dimple is using `d3.time.format` to parse times.  It has to make a choice: is "1-Dec-50", 2050 or 1950?  It chooses 2050:

```
> format = d3.time.format("%d-%b-%y")
> format.parse("1-Dec-50")
  Thu Dec 01 2050 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)
```

Easiest fix is to modify your source data to include century.

Comment: Thank you very much, that was totally the problem.